# Skipping e.preventDefault(); conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html:

```
     <ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
                <li class="login-link">
                    <a href="/Account/Login">LOGIN AREA</a>

                </li>

                <li class="cart">
                    <span id="spCartCount">
                        1
                    </span>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/images/cart.png"></a>           
                </li>
                <li class="login-link">

                      <a href="/Account/LogOff">Log Out</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
```

and Js code:

```
 $("#menu li:not(.cart) a").on("click", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("#menu li.cart > a").next(".popover").hide();
        $(this).next(".popover").fadeToggle();
    });
```

When user clicks Log Out button, they are not redirected to log off page because of  e.preventDefault(); I want to skip  e.preventDefault(); if user clicks Log Off

I tried this:

```
 $("#menu li:not(.cart) a").on("click", function (e) {

          if ($("#menu li:not(.cart) a:contains('LogOff')")) {

        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

            $("#menu li.cart > a").next(".popover").hide();
            $(this).next(".popover").fadeToggle();
        });
```

but it didn't work
How to do it?

Comment: But the tag *doesn't* contain "LogOff". It contains "Log Out".

Comment: I want to do using href or text. href contains LoggOff

Comment: `:contains` doesn't check attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the currently clicked element:

```
$("#menu li:not(.cart) a").bind("click", function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("LogOff") < 0)
        e.preventDefault();

    $("#menu li.cart > a").next(".popover").hide();
    $(this).next(".popover").fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On Event trigger, element needs to be identify first on which it is clicked then check the required value in href/class etc.

'This' keyword can be used to get current element

```
$("#menu li:not(.cart) a").bind("click", function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('LogOff') != -1)
        e.preventDefault();

    $("#menu li.cart > a").next(".popover").hide();
    $(this).next(".popover").fadeToggle();
});
```

or

'e.target' can be used.

```
$("#menu li:not(.cart) a").bind("click", function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('href').indexOf('LogOff') != -1)
        e.preventDefault();

    $("#menu li.cart > a").next(".popover").hide();
    $(this).next(".popover").fadeToggle();
});
```